# Suggestion: Commit Graph (commits/day) for Area 51 Proposals

Tags: feature-request

I think it would be beneficial to see a commit graph for proposals on Area 51. Both a cumulative and graph and a commits per day graph for each proposal would allow potential users see how a proposal is viewed by potential users at large.

Comment: There's already a cumulative graph on the right hand side bar.

Comment: So there is. Now I feel like an idiot! Great minds think alike??